# Getting conditional merged list of disjoint lists in python

Tags: python, list, cplex, gurobi

Given a set of I={0,1,2,3,4}, my code produces feasible optimal routes and the results are look like below: **x[0,2]=1**, **x[2,4]=1**, **x[4,3]=1** (meaning go from node 0 to node 2 then from 2 to 4, then from 4 to 3) and remaining **x[i,j]=0** ( x[0,1]=0 ,x[0,3]=0 , x[2,3]=0,...).

What I need is a **single list** like this: **FinalRoute=[0,2,4,3]** which shows the same concept in a single list.

I tried to append those X where x[i,j]=1 to FinalRoute but I can't figure out the order of visited nodes. Is there any way to create a single list (FinalRoute) by appending x[i,j]s in visited order?

Comment: I think I can't explain the problem clearly! I want a list like [0,2,4,3] (means visit nodes 0,2,4 and 3 in order) GIVEN that I have following lists in hand: x[0,1]=0 , **x[0,2]=1**, x[0,3]=0 , x[0,4]=0 , x[1,2]=0, x[1,3]=0 and x[1,4]=0 , x[2,1]=0 ,x[2,3]=0 , **x[2,4]=1** , x[3,1]=0 , x[3,2]=0, x[3,4]=0 . x[4,1]=0 , x[4,2]=0 ,**x[4,3]=1**

Comment: It means, wherever x[i,j]=1 then add i and j to single list (but preserve the order of visit!)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what x[0, 2] is in python, but assuming you have a 2-dimensional list,
where you reference values as x[0][2], not x[0, 2] and x[0][2] == 1 means that you go from node0 to node2, here is a possible solution:

```
matrix = [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]

path = []
node = 0
while node is not None:
    path.append(node)
    node = matrix[node].index(1) if 1 in matrix[node] else None

print(path)
```

Comment: Thank you Joe. It seems a wise way of doing this; however, you created matrix by observation (most probably). How can I automate creating a list like matrix?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. My matrix is just an example, I assume your code produces something like that and then your problem is how to go through the matrix to get the path, which I gave you answer for. If that is not what you needed, then specify what you need more exactly, ideally on an example.